# Datomic d/as-of is really slow, how can it be improved?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I'm trying to get a Datomic database (free version 0.9.5359) as it were in a particular point in time using:

```
(-> conn d/db (d/as-of (Date. at-epoch)))
```

but this takes a REALLY long time, almost 45 seconds in some cases. Is this expected for largish datasets (I have about 2 Gb of data)? Would using Datomic Pro make this operation faster? Any other tweaks or things one should consider to improve this particular operation?

Comment: Which kind of backend do you use?

Comment: I'm just using Datomic free so I think it just uses local disk